# how do I determine if one list has items contained in another list, then print their index in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to determine if one list has items contained in another list. If that's the case, I want to print the index of such items:

```
List1 = [10, 20, 30]
List2 = [10, 50, 80, 90, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

For example, I want to find `10` in `List1` which is present in `List2`, and print index `0`. Is there any solution or direct function?

Answer (score 0):

```
#Finding intersection between two lists 
inter=set(List1)&set(List2)
for val in inter:
    #prints index of value which contains on both lists
    print List2.index(val)
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer

Comment: @ Pankaj Makwana - Explanataion added :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop and `index` method

**Demo:**

```
List1= [10,20,30] 
List2=[10,50,80,90,20,30,40,50]
for i in List1:
    if i in List2:
        print(List2.index(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```
List1,List2=[10,20,30],[10,50,80,90,20,30,40,50] #input
i = List1[0] #number you're looking for
for index in range(0,len(List2)):
    if List2[index] == i:
        print (index)   # if number is present
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**

```
ls = [i for i,x in enumerate(List2) if x in List1]
print(ls)
```